# pip install can not find versions from Azure Ubuntu

Tags: python, azure, pip

I have created a Python package which is published as a wheel on Azure package registry. For some reason pip will only find the old versions of the package when deploying to a Azure <del>Ubuntu</del> Debian11 machine, whereas all versions are found and correctly installed from my local workstation (also Ubuntu). Starting with a clean virtual environment this is the observed behavior:

Local workstation:

```
bash% pip index versions sonair_dev
WARNING: pip index is currently an experimental command. It may be removed/changed in a future release without prior warning.
sonair_dev (0.0.14)
Available versions: 0.0.14, 0.0.13, 0.0.12, 0.0.11, 0.0.10, 0.0.9, 0.0.8, 0.0.7, 0.0.6, 0.0.5, 0.0.4, 0.0.3, 0.0.2, 0.0.1
  INSTALLED: 0.0.15.dev8
  LATEST:    0.0.14
```

On Azure:

```
bash% pip index versions sonair_dev
WARNING: pip index is currently an experimental command. It may be removed/changed in a future release without prior warning.
sonair_dev (0.0.9)
Available versions: 0.0.9, 0.0.8, 0.0.7, 0.0.6, 0.0.5, 0.0.4, 0.0.3, 0.0.2, 0.0.1
  INSTALLED: 0.0.4
  LATEST:    0.0.9
```

i.e. only a subset of the versions are visible from the Azure client; furthermore on Azure pip insists to install version 0.0.4 - even when i specifically ask for `sonair_dev==0.0.9` which it allegedly can see. The output from `pip install sonair_dev`on azure looks like this:

```
Collecting sonair_dev
  Downloading https://XXX/sonair-dev/0.0.9/sonair_dev-0.0.9-py3-none-any.whl (22 kB)
  Downloading https://XXX/sonair-dev/0.0.8/sonair_dev-0.0.8-py3-none-any.whl (22 kB)
  Downloading https://XXX/sonair-dev/0.0.7/sonair_dev-0.0.7-py3-none-any.whl (22 kB)
  Downloading https://XXX/sonair-dev/0.0.6/sonair_dev-0.0.6-py3-none-any.whl (22 kB)
  Downloading https://XXX/sonair-dev/0.0.5/sonair_dev-0.0.5-py3-none-any.whl (22 kB)
  Downloading https://XXX/sonair-dev/0.0.4/sonair_dev-0.0.4-py3-none-any.whl (22 kB)
```

and the `0.0.4` version is finally installed.

Going from version 0.0.9 to 0.0.10 the package changed from a pure Python package to a package with an included binary rust module; that might be relevant?

Any tips on how to fix/debug this?

Comment: Can you please confirm if the behavior is specific to one Azure VM or if it occurs on multiple VMs? I suspect the package index URL on the Azure VM and that some other package in your project might require sonair_dev version 0.0.4 explicitly. But I am not sure since I can not test it on my end.
Can you please follow this steps and let me know:
`pip config set global.index-url https://your-package-repo-url` ; 

`pip cache purge` ; 

`pip search sonair_dev` ; 

`pip show sonair_dev` ; 

`pip install --no-deps sonair_dev==0.0.9`;

Comment: Thanks for looking into this - I am quite certain the problem was due to version mismatch between the build node (Ubuntu-22.04) and application node (Debian 11).

Answer (score 1):

**Answering this myself**:

1. The `pip` option `--log=path_to_logfile.txt` proved very useful - this log output revealed that `pip` had indeed considered all the versions of my package, but on Azure all the versions with an embedded Rust library the log showed:
   `Skipping link: none of the wheel's tags (xxx-yyy-zzz) are compatible`
2. The package I had created on Ubuntu had tag specification: `cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_34_x86_64`
3. Using the command `pip debug --verbose` listed out all permissable tags - on the Azure WM the newest manylinux platform was: `manylinux_2_31_x86_64` - i.e. the package was built for a newer manylinux/glibc version than what was running on my Azure WM.

I am now creating the package on Ubuntu 20.04 as well- that solved the problem.

Comment: I noted down your solution, :) just in case I will encounter a similar issue.